# Issues Lining Up Content using Bootstrap Grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See the page and code here: http://deadlydesigns.com/bootstrap/

Hello, I am new to Bootstrap. I have been implementing Bootstrap to a static HTML page and can't seem to figure out how to align the cart, popular artists, and popular genres correctly on the right-hand side.  Some others helped me get it lined up with the art description; however, it needs to be lined up with the artwork title. While doing this there also need to be space in-between the art title and the right-side panels. [Here is how it needs to look](http://deadlydesigns.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-components.png).

Also, my search button at the top is not lining up withe the search text input field. I am not sure why. It was lining up then something got messed up and I can't figure out what it is.

Thank you! Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the content of the first `col-md-10` element (the `<h2>` and `<p>` elements) to the top of the second `col-md-10` (before the `col-md-5`, etc contents). Then you can delete the first `col-md-10` element. After that, you can merge your `div.row` elements and everything should line up like you want:

**New contents of `div.container`**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> <!-- row 1 -->
         <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h2>Self-portrait in a Straw Hat</h2><p>By <a href="#">Louise Elisabeth Lebrun</a></p><div class="col-md-5">
                                <img src="images/art/113010.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Self-portrait in a Straw Hat">   
                            </div> <!-- col-md-5 -->
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <p>
                                The painting appears, after cleaning, to be an autograph replica of a picture, the original of which was painted in Brussels in 1782 in free imitation of Rubens's 'Chapeau de Paille', which LeBrun had seen in Antwerp. It was exhibited in Paris in 1782 at the Salon de la Correspondance. LeBrun's original is recorded in a private collection in France. 
                                </p>
                                <p class="price">$700</p>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span>
                                        Add to Wish List  
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                                        Add to Shopping Cart
                                        </button>
                                    </div> <!-- end btn-group -->

                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">Product Details</div>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <th>Date:</th>
                                            <td>1782</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Medium:</th>
                                            <td>Oil on canvas</td>
                                        </tr>  
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Dimensions:</th>
                                            <td>98cm x 71cm</td>
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Home:</th>
                                            <td><a href="#">National Gallery, London</a></td>
                                        </tr>  
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Genres:</th>
                                            <td><a href="#">Realism</a>, <a href="#">Rococo</a></td>
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Subjects:</th>
                                            <td><a href="#">People</a>, <a href="#">Arts</a></td>
                                        </tr>     
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </div> <!-- end panel panel-default -->                            
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            </div><!-- end col-md-7 -->
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3>Similar Products </h3> 
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="images/art/thumbs/116010.jpg" alt="...">
                                <div class="caption">
                                     <p class="similarTitle"><a href="#">Artist Holding a Thistle</a></p>
                                     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> View</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> Wish</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</button>
                                </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
                            <div class="col-md-3">              
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="images/art/thumbs/120010.jpg" alt="...">
                                  <div class="caption">
                                         <p class="similarTitle"><a href="#">Portrait of Eleanor of Toledo</a></p>
                                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> View</button>
                                         <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> Wish</button>
                                         <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
                            <div class="col-md-3">  
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="images/art/thumbs/107010.jpg" alt="...">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                         <p class="similarTitle"><a href="#">Madame de Pompadour</a></p>
                                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> View</button>
                                         <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> Wish</button>
                                         <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
                            <div class="col-md-3">  
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="images/art/thumbs/106020.jpg" alt="...">
                                <div class="caption">
                                     <p class="similarTitle"><a href="#">Girl with a Pearl Earring</a></p>
                                     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> View</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> Wish</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</button>
                                </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div> <!-- col-md-3 -->
                        </div></div><div class="col-md-2">  
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">Cart </h3>
                                </div> <!-- end panel-heading -->
                                <div class="media">
                                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                    <img class="media-object" src="images/art/tiny/116010.jpg" alt="..." width="32">
                                    </a>
                                    <p class="media-body"><a class="media-heading" href="#">Artist Holding a Thistle</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media">
                                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                    <img class="media-object" src="images/art/tiny/113010.jpg" alt="..." width="32">
                                    </a>
                                    <p class="media-body"><a class="media-heading" href="#">Self-portrait in a Straw Hat</a></p>

                                    <strong class="cartText">Subtotal: <span class="cartTotal">$1200</span></strong>
                                    <div>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> Edit</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Checkout</button>    
                                    </div> <!-- end buttons -->
                                </div> <!-- end media -->
                            </div> <!-- end panel panel-primary -->

                             <div class="panel panel-info">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                   <h3 class="panel-title">Popular Artists</h3>
                                </div> <!-- panel-heading -->
                                   <ul class="list-group">
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Caravaggio</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Cezanne</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Matisse</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Michelangelo</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Picasso</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Raphael</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Van Gogh</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                            </div> <!-- panel panel-info -->

                            <div class="panel panel-info">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                   <h3 class="panel-title">Popular Genres</h3>
                                </div> <!-- panel-heading -->   
                                   <ul class="list-group">
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Baroque</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Cubism</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Impressionism</a></li>
                                      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Renaissance</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                             </div> <!-- panel panel-info -->
                        </div><!-- col-md-10 -->

                 <!-- 2st row -->
</div> <!-- 1st row -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation! That worked! You can see how it looks now by going to the original link I posted. I figured out the search button issue too.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of some assistance.